# javascript: access all variables of a parent function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I decided to create a `funcB` function that I call from `funcA`. I want all variables from funcA to be available in the funcB so func B can change that variables.
How to modify the code below so it meets my requirements? I doubt passing all variables it the only possible and the best way.

```
function funcB(){
alert(var1);//how to make it alert 5
alert(var20);//how to make it alert 50
}
function funcA(){
var var1=5;
...
var var20=50;
funcB();
}
```

Comment: javaScript variables are scoped to the functions they are defined in.

Comment: This should do: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/7Murm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    one : "A",
    two : "B",
    fnA : function() {
        this.fnB(); // without fnB method result will be displayed as A B, with fnB as C D
        console.log(this.one + " " + this.two);
    },
    fnB : function() {
        this.one = "C";
        this.two = "D";
    }
};

obj.fnA();
```

`this` keyword refers to `obj` object

You can define object with properties and methods inside it. With methods all the variables can be manipulated as you wish, from this example with `fnB` I'm changing values of properties which are displayed from `fnA` method

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6h23/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

One way is to drop the `var` keyword:

```
function funcB(){
    alert(var1);//how to make it alert 5
    alert(var20);//how to make it alert 50
}

function funcA(){
    var1 = 5;
    var20 = 50;

    funcB();
}
```

This will expose them to the global scope so `funcB` can access them. Notice you can also create the varaibles in the global scope itself, with the `var` keyword, but both methods will ultimately have the same effect.

Note:

1. This may not work if there is already a `var1` or `var20` in the global scope. In such case, it will modify the global value and may result in unwanted errors.
2. This method is not preferred for official code, and is bad practice [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as when you declare a variable with the `var` keyword, they are `scoped` to the function in which they are declared.

If you avoid the `var` keyword, they are instead defined as a `global variable`. This is deemed very bad practice.

I would recommend you read up on [javascript coding patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), particularly the module pattern.

For example:

```
var myNamespace = (function () {
  var foo, bar;  
  return {
    func1: function() {
      foo = "baz";
      console.log(foo);
    },

    func2: function (input) {
      foo = input;
      console.log(foo);
    }
  };

})();
```

Usage:

```
myNamespace.func1();
// "baz"
myNamespace.func2("hello");
// "hello"
```